# Wildcards in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

With the following code, I'm trying to pass a wildcard to my controller but I'm not sure how I can pass the URL dynamically and I'm not sure how to do this without creating a route for each url, which would take forever. Currently, I'm attempting to do it like so:

```
<a href="{{ route('purchase-get') }}/$item->name">
```

Here is the rest of the code

```
                  <tbody class="text-center">
                      @foreach (array_chunk($items->all(), 3) as $item_each)
                      <tr>
                          @foreach($item_each as $item)
                            <td>
                              <a href="{{ route('purchase-get') }}/$item->name">
                                {{ HTML::image($item->image_url, 'item-image', array('class' => 'item-image-row')) }}
                                <h4>{{ $item->item }}</h4>
                                <span class="text-muted">{{ $item->cost }}</span>
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          @endforeach
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: can you post your routes file please

Comment: You really should create a rule for each URL, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to a wildcard with named routes:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', function()
{
    $slug = 'product-1';
    return '<a href="'.URL::route('products', $slug).'">link to product</a>';
}));
```

Then catch the names route with the wildcard slug:

```
Route::get('products/{slug}', array('as' => 'products', function($slug)
{
    $product = Product::where('slug','=',$slug)->first();
    return $product;
}));
```